# New Spring 2.4.0 Data Rest project reports is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors

Tags: spring-boot

I am starting a new spring-boot project using data-rest and I noticed a lot of INFO message reporting "Bean 'X' of type [Y] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors.

Is this a cause for concerns?

To reproduce issue, create project from spring initializr 2.4.0, mvn, Java 11 with only data Rest Repositories as dependencies.

```
./mvnw clean install
```

Running the default test class from the generated project produces lots of

```
2020-12-01 13:35:05.746  INFO 21452 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-01 13:35:05.758  INFO 21452 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-01 13:35:05.769  INFO 21452 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.OrderAwarePluginRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-01 13:35:05.773  INFO 21452 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '_relProvider' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-01 13:35:05.781  INFO 21452 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'messageResolver' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.MessageSourceResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please don't link to github repositories, but instead provide a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: @rethab edited ticket with suggestions